# Run latest date records

Tags: sql

I'm trying to run latest/recent year records from a set of data in a table. Ex:

```
10903          09C2D381-59B2-E411-BD0F-1CC1DE2561D4       2014-12-31
10903          D15F5801-5AB2-E411-BD0F-1CC1DE2561D4       2014-12-31
10903          4861F3DB-7DC9-E511-80E2-8CDCD4AF21E4       2014-12-31
10903          C1D6898E-D6ED-E611-80EA-8CDCD4AF21E4       2016-12-31
10903          00D7898E-D6ED-E611-80EA-8CDCD4AF21E4       2016-12-31
10903          A1B214AC-150C-E811-80F1-8CDCD4AF21E4       2017-12-31
10903          08E30EB2-150C-E811-80F1-8CDCD4AF21E4       2017-12-31
10903          889BEB0D-DD29-E911-8105-8CDCD4AF21E4       2018-12-31
10903          8F9BEB0D-DD29-E911-8105-8CDCD4AF21E4       2018-12-31
```

from the above data, for the identifier 10903, we have  2 records for recent year 2018. I want to run a query to get all records from recent year.

I've 300 identifiers to run. Could you help me with a query?

Comment: Also specify the expected result.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Thanks. I'm expecting results something like this ISIN Document id Report Date
  
AT0000606306 D56A8478-6647-E911-8105-8CDCD4AF21E4 12/31/18
AT0000606306 5B467866-2A46-E911-8105-8CDCD4AF21E4 12/31/18
AT0000606306 74CB0B7D-A445-E911-8105-8CDCD4AF21E4 12/31/18
AT0000606306 AB262533-2046-E911-8105-8CDCD4AF21E4 12/31/18
AT0000606306 6ACD0B7D-A445-E911-8105-8CDCD4AF21E4 12/31/18
AT0000606306 077843D9-9B45-E911-8105-8CDCD4AF21E4 12/31/18

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit the question instead.

Comment: You can filter your date column using max(year(date)).
So it will be => select * from table where year(date) = (select max(year(date)) from table);
It will fetch you recent year like '2018'. ie select * from table where year(date) = 2018;

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub-query :

```
select t.*
from table t
where year(t.date) = (select max(year(t1.date)) from table t1 where t1.identifier = t.identifier);
```

You can also ranking function `rank()` if your DBMS support :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, rank() over (partition by t.identifier order by year(t.date) desc) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

Function `year()` is product specific.